# Unable to debug: ntdll.dll Access violation error for hello world C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When trying to **Debug** in Visual C++ 2008 Exress on Windows XP SP3
it's showing

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7c91b21a (ntdll.dll) in Hello.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000010.

--------------------------8><--------------------------
// Hello.cpp 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hi All" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
--------------------------8><--------------------------

------ Build started: Project: Hello, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
Hello.cpp
Linking...
Embedding manifest...
Build log was saved at "file://c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
Hello - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========


:
:
------ BuildLog.htm -------------------------------------------------------

Creating temporary file "c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001889289124.rsp" with contents
[
/Od /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /c /ZI /TP .\Hello.cpp
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001889289124.rsp /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
Creating temporary file "c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001989289124.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"C:\wrk\Hello\Debug\Hello.exe" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\Hello.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\wrk\Hello\Debug\Hello.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

".\Debug\Hello.obj"
]
Creating command line "link.exe @c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001989289124.rsp /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"
Creating temporary file "c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001A89289124.rsp" with contents
[
/outputresource:"..\Debug\Hello.exe;#1" /manifest

.\Debug\Hello.exe.intermediate.manifest
]
Creating command line "mt.exe @c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\RSP00001A89289124.rsp /nologo"
Creating temporary file "c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\BAT00001B89289124.bat" with contents
[
@echo Manifest resource last updated at %TIME% on %DATE% > .\Debug\mt.dep
]
Creating command line "c:\wrk\Hello\Hello\Debug\BAT00001B89289124.bat"

====== BuildLog.htm =======================================================
:
:
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus and some other software usually protected from being debugged. Look at the Output window. Check what DLLs were loaded immediately before exception.